# Use NuSoap basic auth webservice in C#

Tags: c#, credentials, nusoap

He there,

I have a basic webservice which works in C# if i remove the Basic auth option. But when i add the Basic auth meganism and set NetworkCredentials in C# I get this wierd error.

C# does authenticate correctly but after that something goed wrong.

```
Service s = new Service();
s.Credentials = new Credentials("jan", "password");

String result = s.getData();
```

The error i get is: HTTP-status 400: Bad Request. When I look in my error_log i see this error:

[Fri Jul 23 14:53:33 2010] [error] [client 192.165.10.47] Invalid URI in request 1POST /testzooi/rpc/index.php HTTP/1.1

Comment: I have absolutely the same problem :( Did you manage to solve it? Also, it's interesting that basic authentication for webservice works on my development machine and on one our website hosted on Hostgator, but it doesn't work on our VPS (as you said, 400: Bad request and invalid URI in apache logs). Also, if I open the webservie in the browser and specify login and password everything works as expected. PS. I use PHP nusoap library on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking with mono #c and I see no Service Object if it's 
System.Web.Services or a instatiation of a WSDL service 
the Service.Credentials seems to be to set a bollean value and not the Credentials object.